# Exchange data between two Forms and refresh the Form as data is changed

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I am trying to send data from Form 2 to Form 1 that will refresh when i update the data in the textbox. I can send over data but i cannot make it refresh. i assume i have to put it somewhere that refreshes the values of team1, but I guess the way im sending data over is read only and can't be dynamically changed

```
    //In Form 1
            Form2 frm = new Form2();
            Team1Lbl.Text = frm.team1;

    //In form 2
        public string team1
        {
            get { return Team1Name.Text + " - " + team1score.ToString(); }
        }
```

Comment: The way you did it should refresh `Team1Lbl`. The question is: Where (and when) are you calling this code? Might `Team1Lbl.Text` be changed again afterwards by another piece of code? Is the code runnnig in an endless loop and thus preventing the form from refreshing?

Comment: What i was trying was to put the string in the Form2 class and update it on TextChange Functioon, but I cannot use it in TextChanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending data, you are retrieving data from another form. How should `Form1` know when the text in `Form2` changed?

You can declare an event in `Form2` that tells `Form1` that the information should be updated

```
// In Form2
public event Action<string> TeamInfoChanged;

private void OnTeamInfoChanged()
{
    var handler = TeamInfoChanged;
    if (handler != null) {
        handler(Team1Name.Text + " - " + team1score);
    }
}

private void Team1Name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnTeamInfoChanged();
}
```

In `Form1` you can then attach to this event:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 frm;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm = new Form2();
        frm.TeamInfoChanged += new Action<string>(frm_TeamInfoChanged);
        frm.Show();
    }

    void frm_TeamInfoChanged(string info)
    {
        Team1Lbl.Text = info;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay. I tried this but it will not post to Form1 now, I may have it in a bad place. What function should i be putting the frm.TeamInfoChanged Line in. Also when i try to debug i get an error could not load file. but when i run without debugging it runs fine

Comment: Changed Assembly name and debug works fine now. the problem is is that the code im putting in Form1 isn't being hit.

Comment: Double click the `Team1Name` textbox of Form2 in the form designer in order to attach the TextChanged event. Just by coping my code into the form the event won't be attached.

Comment: I did that... i just had a simple mistake of putting it in a place that wasn't called. my fault. but its still not getting updated data in Form1. in Debug when i start editing the textbox the program breaks as it should but the lbl isn't being updated with what i put in the Txtbox

Comment: It works for me. Is `Team1Lbl` really visible? Try putting text into it manually in the designer.

Comment: Yes its visible i put a string to the lbl in Form_Load function and it showed up.

Comment: Is `Team1Name_TextChanged` being called? Is `OnTeamInfoChanged` (and espesically the line `handler(Team1Name.Text + " - " + team1score);`) being called? Is `frm_TeamInfoChanged` being called?

Comment: Okay. now this is easier, `handler(Team1Name.Text..)`line is not being called

Comment: It's because no handler is attached to the event (`handler == null`). Probably `frm.TeamInfoChanged += new Action<string>(frm_TeamInfoChanged);` is not being called.

Comment: yes you are right. where should i put that line that it will be called upon updating the textbox

Comment: The line not being called is okay. It's the line `frm.TeamInfoChanged += ...` which must be called (resulting in `handler` to be `null` when not called). Call `frm.TeamInfoChanged += ...` just after `frm = new Form2();` in order to subscribe to the event. Then `handler(Team1Name.Text..)` will be called also.

Comment: okay, my problem is no matter which function i put the `frm = new Form2()` and `frm.TeamInfoChanged +=...` it doesn't update. is there a certain function im supposed to put those 2 lines in. thats hte only problem i seem to be having

Comment: lol. i looked it up and realized what i was missing right when you changed it... I knew it had to be there but i was missing the show().... so i was showing a form that i wasn't subscribed to... Im sorry for my amateur ignorance